# ClassNotFoundException using ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, objectinputstream

I have a class that implements serializable

```
package lligafutbolserial.aaron.gomez;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Equip implements Comparable<Equip>, Serializable {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
transient Integer puntsLliga;
transient String nomEquip;
HashMap<Integer, Jugador> jugadors;
transient Scanner in;

public Equip(String nom) {
    this.nomEquip = nom;
    this.puntsLliga = 0;
    this.jugadors = new HashMap();
}

public HashMap<Integer, Jugador> getJugadors() {
    return jugadors;
}

public void setJugadors(HashMap<Integer, Jugador> jugadors) {
    this.jugadors = jugadors;
}

public String getNom() {
    return nomEquip;
}

public int getPunts() {
    return puntsLliga;
}

public void incrementaPunts(int punts) {
    puntsLliga += punts;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Equip: puntsLliga=" + puntsLliga + ", nomEquip=" + nomEquip;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Equip o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return o.puntsLliga.compareTo(this.puntsLliga);
}

public HashMap<Integer, Jugador> afegirJugadors() {
    in = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        if (jugadors.size() > 0) {
            in.nextLine();
        }
        Jugador jugador = new Jugador();
        System.out.println("Nom del jugador: ");
        jugador.setNom(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Cognom del jugador: ");
        jugador.setCognom(in.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Dorsal del jugador: ");
        jugador.setDorsal(in.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Edat del jugador: ");
        jugador.setEdat(in.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Dona'm l'al�ada del jugador: ");
        jugador.setAlsada(in.nextFloat());
        jugador.setGols(0);
        jugador.setEquip(this);
        jugadors.put(jugador.getDorsal(), jugador);
    } while (jugadors.size() < 15);
    return jugadors;
}

public boolean afegirUnJugador() {
    in = new Scanner(System.in);

    Jugador jugador = new Jugador();

    System.out.println("Nom del jugador: ");
    jugador.setNom(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Cognom del jugador: ");
    jugador.setCognom(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Dorsal del jugador: ");
    jugador.setDorsal(in.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Edat del jugador: ");
    jugador.setEdat(in.nextInt());
    System.out.println("Dona'm l'al�ada del jugador: ");
    jugador.setAlsada(in.nextFloat());
    jugador.setGols(0);
    jugador.setEquip(this);
    if (jugadors.put(jugador.getDorsal(), jugador) == null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

I write to the file with the next method:

```
public void escriureTot() throws IOException{
    String nomFitxer = "";
    for(Equip e : equips){
        System.out.println(e.getNom());
        nomFitxer = "LligaBBVA/"+ e.getNom();
        writerTot = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(nomFitxer));
        writerTot.writeObject(e);
        writerTot.close();
    }
}
```

I use this loop to get the filename and read from the file.

```
        for (Path fitxers : ds) {
        System.out.println(fitxers.toString());
        System.out.println(fitxers.toString().substring(10));
        String nomEquip = fitxers.toString().substring(10);
        ObjectInputStream llegir = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("LligaBBVA/" + nomEquip));
        equip = (Equip) llegir.readObject();
        equips.add(equip);
        llegir.close();
    }
```

But when i try equip = (Equip) llegir.readObject(); this error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lligafutbol.aaron.gomez.Equip
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:626)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1613)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1518)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1774)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1351)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:371)
at lligafutbolserial.aaron.gomez.Lliga.<init>(Lliga.java:51)
at lligafutbolserial.aaron.gomez.Principal.main(Principal.java:14)
```

I've tried to be the clearest possible, sorry if its hard to understand. Thx m8's!

Comment: Looks like the project where you're reading the data doesn't have this `Equip` class defined.

Comment: are `Principal`, and `Equip` classes in same package? If no, you imported `Equip`?

Comment: if your `lligafutbol.aaron.gomez.Equip` class in inside a JAR, make sure to add that the `Principal`'s class-path. How exactly are you invoking your code ?

Comment: All the classes are in the same package.

Comment: This one `lligafutbolserial.aaron.gomez.Principal` and `lligafutbol.aaron.gomez.Equip` are completely different packages :)

Comment: I copy pasted the project, they are same package but tries to get the other one, how can i change that? Coz actually they are all on the same package.

Comment: Make sure you use the correct import of `Equip` at the top. It should be same in both the files - where you're doing `writeObject(e)` and another file where you're doing `readObject()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have changed package names between writing (at least one of) the files and trying to read them back.  You present code for class `lligafutbolserial.aaron.gomez.Equip`, but the class of the object Java is trying to read is `lligafutbol.aaron.gomez.Equip` ("lligafutbolserial" vs. "lligafutbol").

Note, too, that you appear to be naming -- and presumably arranging -- your packages in an odd way.  Since package names are mapped to a directory tree by the compiler, it is normally most convenient to order the segments from most general to most specific.  That is, `gomez.aaron.lligafutbolserial`. Substantially *all* Java code is named and arranged that way.

Comment: Yeah, thats what i actually made, but how do i change the class Equip that i want to pick? Coz i dont want lligafutbol.aaron.gomez.Equip anymore, i want lligafutbolserial.aaron.gomez.Equip. Thanks a lot!

Comment: correct your `import` statement in `Principal` class, if you want to use the one in same package, just remove the explicit import for `lligafutbol.aaron.gomez.Equip`

Comment: They actually are all in the same package, but the error will still come out. Im sorry, never happen this before... I mean, i've checked the imports and the package, all at the same package.

Comment: The problem is not with your cast, it is that you have serialized an object of a class that is not available when you try to deserialize it.  You cannot change an object's class via serialization/deserialization.  Java serialization format is primarily for object *transmission*; it is not well suited for long-term storage.  If you don't want to change your package name back to the original, then you'll have to serialize new objects.  Make sure to delete all the old files from disk.

Comment: Thanks, ill try that and post the result!

Comment: Thanky you very much, its been really helpfull and i've learned a bit about serializable. This sorted out my prob!

Answer (score 0):

Your code has

```
package lligafutbolserial.aaron.gomez;
//...
public class Equip
```

The error message says:

```
ClassNotFoundException: lligafutbol.aaron.gomez.Equip
```

Apparently you serialized an object of another class Equip in another package `lligafutbol`. You must use identical classes.